# Multi User Chat room join with owner privilege android + asmack

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

**Multi User Chat Room Join**

How to join a multi user chat room as "owner" in android?. Currently I am joining the multi user chat room using the following code. However I am joining as a participant only.

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, group);
muc.join(nickNameOfUser, password);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MUC members/owners list maintained on the MUC server side, and automatically grant you owner privileges on create/join room. If you not receive owner privileges, then room was created by someone else.

Comment: @vitalyster..evenif I join a room which was created by me, I am still joining as a participant. I am creating the room with the following code.    Roster roster = getRoster(account);
roster.createGroup(nick);

Comment: This is **NOT** a room creation code, use:
`MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, group);
muc.create(nickNameOfUser);`

Comment: @ vitalyster...I tried creating room with object of MultiUserChat as provoded by you. But it is giving me a ClassCastException.

Comment: ClassCastException thrown when you are trying to cast incompatible objects, nothing related to MUC ownership. Show your full code and full error.

Answer (score 1):

```
// In Smack version 4.1.4 i am able to join Room by following way.

MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
manager.addInvitationListener(new InvitationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void invitationReceived(XMPPConnection conn, MultiUserChat room, String inviter, String reason, String password, Message message) {
                        try {
                            room.join(userName);
                        } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```